# Angular 6/7 Ionic redirect to a URL but close any open modal windows

Tags: angular, ionic4

Is there a way to redirect to a URL in angular 6/7 and for it to force the close of any open modal windows or basically just replace the entire page with the new url?

Reason: I have an interceptor that checked the token/refresh token via the backend API and if it determines the token AND the refresh are no longer valid it needs to redirect the user to the login page. This all works just fine if the user is on a "page". if the user is on a modal window e.g. an edit modal popup and the request to the API fires the interceptor to redirect, the page does indeed redirect to the login page but the modal window is still there on top.

Is there a way to force a redirect to render the new page which closes any open modals? I don't have a reference to the modal from the interceptor.

I am trying either of these:

this.router.navigateByUrl('/account/login');

and

this.navCtrl.navigateRoot('/account/login');

and neither close off the modal or replace the entire page.

Thank you

Rowie.

Interceptor Class:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpUserEvent, HttpEvent, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, throwError } from "rxjs";
import { switchMap, filter, take, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Injectable, Injector } from "@angular/core";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
import { NavController } from "@ionic/angular";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";


@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    private isRefreshing = false;
    private refreshTokenSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

    constructor(private router: Router, private navCtrl: NavController, private inj: Injector) { }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        let authSrv = this.inj.get(AuthService);

        if (authSrv.AccessToken) {
            request = this.addToken(request, authSrv.AccessToken);
        }
        return next.handle(request).pipe(catchError(error => {
            if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
                switch (error.status) {
                    case 400:
                        return this.handle400Error(error);
                    case 401:
                        return this.handle401Error(request, next);
                    case 403:
                        return this.handle403Error(error);
                }
            }
            else {
                return throwError(error);
            }
        }));
    };

    private addToken(request: HttpRequest<any>, token: string) {
        let authSrv = this.inj.get(AuthService);
        return request.clone({
            setHeaders: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + authSrv.AccessToken
            }
        });
    }

    private handle400Error(error) {
        this.isRefreshing = false;
        if (error && error.status === 400 && error.error && error.error.error === 'invalid_grant') {
            // If we get a 400 and the error message is 'invalid_grant', the token is no longer valid so logout.
            let authSrv = this.inj.get(AuthService);
            authSrv.logout();
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/account/login');

        }
        return throwError(error);
    }

    private handle403Error(error) {
        //Forbidden - tried to load something not allowed - log the user out
        this.isRefreshing = false;
        let authSrv = this.inj.get(AuthService);
        authSrv.logout();
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/account/login');

        return throwError(error);
    }

    private handle401Error(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

        if (!this.isRefreshing) {

            console.log('Refreshing token');

            this.isRefreshing = true;
            this.refreshTokenSubject.next(null);

            let authSrv = this.inj.get(AuthService);
            return authSrv.refrehToken().pipe(
                switchMap((token: any) => {
                    this.isRefreshing = false;
                    this.refreshTokenSubject.next(token.access_token);
                    console.log('Refreshing token - complete');
                    return next.handle(this.addToken(request, token.access_token));
                })
            )

        } else {
            return this.refreshTokenSubject.pipe(
                filter(token => token != null),
                take(1),
                switchMap(jwt => {
                    return next.handle(this.addToken(request, jwt));
                })
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you'll have to close the modal explicitly. Do you have some sample code to work with?

Comment: This is too broad to be answerable. You can do pretty much whatever you want to do with Angular, but it means you’ll have to write code to do it.

Comment: OK, to make it more generic: I have "Page A" - when I click the edit button on "Page A" - it opens a Modal Window "Modal A". user interacts with "Modal A" which fires an API request to the backend API. This is intercepted with my Interceptor code. The interceptor determines the Access Token has expired and "REDIRECTS TO THE LOGIN PAGE". However, the "Modal A" window is left open. How can I redirect from the interceptor page and have it close any modals that are left open? I don't have a reference to the Modal A on the interceptor class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a work-around to my problem, if it helps anyone else with the same issue. That being to redirect to say the Login page and for that redirect to force close of any modal objects: Not pretty but it works for me:

Within my Interceptor class, where I need to force the user to the login page, I have create a closeModals method which simply finds all ion-modal objects and removes them from the DOM before redirecting.

Happy days.

```
private closeModals(){
    var modals = document.getElementsByTagName("ion-modal");
    [].forEach.call(modals, function (el:any) {
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
    });
}
```

Comment: This helped as a workaround in my Ionic 6 React app where I was using <Redirect /> after login using a Dialog, but the modal was still stuck because it would need to render first with the new isOpen=false state.
I guess as an alternative, the redirect could be postponed to after the dismiss of the dialog finished, such as via the ionModalDidDismiss event. But that might also need additional handling in the App component to stick in the Login page even when already signed in. Consequently, the above is a handy workaround to do the job. Even though there might be better ways out there ;-)

Comment: I need something like this to.  In my case on pageA, modalA is opened...and while opened the pageA is directed to pageB...and modalA stays open over pageB - which is intended.  But when the user clicks the modal close button, because the controller moved away from pageA, the close button doesn't work.  so I need another method that can close ModalA from pageB.  I have not found a native angular way to do this yet so I am trying to use your solution, however I am getting an error on the `:` in the `...function (el:any)...` part of the code.  Any ideas?